# how to get background color from button with action listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

i am trying to make game like lite-bright using java GUI components. i am stuck here that how can i get background color of my button when an action occures ? in JAVA API there is methods like `JButton.getBackground()`.

in my programme when i click the button i want the background color of that clicked button and i want to draw the oval of that color at specific location.

this is my code

```
/**
* Action Listener for Buttons
*/
class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setColor(getBackground());  // here i want to get background color as light blue.
    }
}
```

```
b1 = new JButton("o");
Color c1 = new Color(100,255,255);// this is light blue color
b1.setBackground(c1);

ActionListener listener = new ButtonAction();
b1.addActionListener(listener);
```

```
/**
* this method will set vakue of the color and that color will use to draw oval 
* filled with that color.
*/
public void setColor(Color C) {
    this.c = C;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the button pressed by calling `.getSource()` on the ActionListener's ActionEvent parameter:

```
class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // get the button that was pressed 
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();

        // get its background Color
        Color color = button.getBackground();

        // TODO: do what you want with the color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The getBackground in `setColor(getBackground());` refers to the `this.getBackground()` which is the class where you are implementing your code. This is a JFrame or some other object which has a getBackground, but not your Button b1.

You want to get the event source component (i.e. the JButton which was clicked) and get its background color (`((JComponent)e.getSource()).getBackground()`).